# php artisan serve slow when loading another page or submit form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a project that use laravel 5.6. I always use the `php artisan serve` for developing my apps. But in this case, when I click submit on page that on my browser, artisan serve loads the page so slow. The command prompt just shows this

```
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Fri May  4 21:10:47 2018] 127.0.0.1:50133 [200]: /css/materialize.min.css
[Fri May  4 21:10:47 2018] 127.0.0.1:50147 [200]: /js/materialize.min.js
[Fri May  4 2
```

I don't know what happens with this artisan serve. So what should I do apart moving my project app to htdocs?
I'm using windows 10

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at
Laravel Valet. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet

For linux.
https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux/

Comment: Thank you! I will look the Laravel Valet